# Postgres INNER JOIN query issue

Tags: php, postgresql

I have two tables user and discovery but i'm unable to query them using join in postgres and php. My query is

```
$query = 'SELECT discovery.id,user.avatar,user.name,user.city,user.country,
discovery.image,discovery.likes,discovery.pincount FROM discovery
WHERE (discovery.id=$1)
INNER JOIN user ON (discovery.user=user.id)';
$res = pg_query_params($query, array($_POST['discovery_id']));
```

I am getting error

```
syntax error at or near "."
```

I have a field user in discovery table and also a table named user.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that INNER JOIN should come before WHERE...

Comment: i changed it but still getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
$query = 'SELECT d.id, u.avatar, u.name, u.city, u.country, 
d.image, d.likes, d.pincount FROM "discovery" AS d
INNER JOIN "user" AS u ON (d.user = u.id) WHERE (d.id = $id)';
$res = pg_query_params($query, array($_POST['discovery_id']));
```

The issue occured due to `user` is a reserved word on postgressql (postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html), The table name `user` without `"` is referred as a keyword

Comment: still getting same error: syntax error at or near "."

Comment: thanks, but it says "column u.id does not exist" but user table have a column named "id" what could be the issue?

Comment: variable name should not begin with a number `$1`

Comment: i changed `d.id = $1` to `d.id = $id`

Comment: this got it working $query = 'SELECT d.id, u.avatar, u.name, u.city, u.country, 
d.image, d.likes, d.pincount FROM discovery AS d
INNER JOIN "user" AS u ON (d.user= u.id) WHERE (d.id=$1)';

Comment: The issue may caused  due to `user` is a reserved word on postgressql (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html), The table name `user` without  `"` is referred as a keyword

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
$query = "SELECT discovery.id,user.avatar,user.name,user.city,user.country,
discovery.image,discovery.likes,discovery.pincount FROM discovery d1
INNER JOIN user d2 ON d1.user=d2.id WHERE d1.id='1'";
```